# Join the types of std::variant<a, b, c> and std::variant<x, y, z>

Tags: c++

Is there a way to declare a third variant from two existing variant types which contains the union of both variant types?

```
#include <variant>

using Var1 = std::variant<int, bool>;
using Var2 = std::variant<float, double>;

// both lines should yield the same
using MergedVariant = VariantUnion<Var1, Var2>; // <-- how to do this?
using MergedVariant = std::variant<int, bool, float, double>; // expected
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use such a helper type for the deduction:

```
#include <variant>

template <class ...Args>
struct VariantUnionHelper;

template <class ...Args1, class ...Args2>
struct VariantUnionHelper<std::variant<Args1...>, std::variant<Args2...>> {
    using type = std::variant<Args1..., Args2...>;
};
```

Together with a convenient type alias

```
template <class Variant1, class Variant2>
using VariantUnion = typename VariantUnionHelper<Variant1, Variant2>::type;
```

this allows for the following use case

```
using Var1 = std::variant<int, long, short>;
using Var2 = std::variant<bool, char, double>;
VariantUnion<Var1, Var2> joined;
```

and passes the following compile time check.

```
#include <type_traits>

static_assert(std::is_same_v<VariantUnion<Var1, Var2>,
     std::variant<int, long, short, bool, char, double>>);
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution form lubgr is good, but has couple shortcomings. It accepts only two arguments, works only for `std::variant`, doesn't respect naming in style: `struct X` and `using X_t` to be similar to STL.

```cpp
template <class... Args>
struct template_concat;

template <template <class...> class T, class... Args1, class... Args2, typename... Remaining>
struct template_concat<T<Args1...>, T<Args2...>, Remaining...> {
    using type = typename template_concat<T<Args1..., Args2...>, Remaining...>::type;
};

template <template <class...> class T, class... Args1>
struct template_concat<T<Args1...>> {
    using type = T<Args1...>;
};

template <class... Args>
using template_concat_t = typename template_concat<Args...>::type;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<
    template_concat_t<
        std::variant<int, long, short>,
        std::variant<bool, char, double>>,
    std::variant<int, long, short, bool, char, double>>);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/T37KE81nf

I do not like `template_concat` name, but I can't come up with better version.