# How to use C++20 concepts in place of Abstract Interfaces as shared_ptr template parameter

Tags: c++, interface, c++20, c++-concepts

While reading [Raytracing in a Weekend](https://raytracing.github.io/books/RayTracingInOneWeekend.html#surfacenormalsandmultipleobjects/anabstractionforhittableobjects), I tried to use concept instead of interface. An interface `Hittable` with a method `hit` is given. And I used this concept to replace it.

```cpp
class IHittable { // I for Interface
public:
    virtual bool hit(
        const Ray& ray, 
        f64 t_min, f64 t_max, 
        HitRecord& rec) const = 0;
};


template <typename Obj>
concept Hittable = requires(
    const Obj& obj, const Ray& r,
    f64 t_min, f64 t_max,
    HitRecord& rec) 
{
    { obj.hit(r, t_min, t_max, rec) } -> std::same_as<bool>;
};
```

Now, a new aggregate class [`HittableList`](https://raytracing.github.io/books/RayTracingInOneWeekend.html#surfacenormalsandmultipleobjects/alistofhittableobjects) is given that contains a vector of `IHittable` object ptrs. It implements that `hit` method as well that calls each `IHittable` object's `hit` method one by one to check all of them.

```cpp
class HittableList : public IHittable {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<IHittable>> objects;
    ...
    virtual bool hit(
        const Ray& ray, 
        f64 t_min, f64 t_max, 
        HitRecord& rec) const override { ... }
};
```

How can I create a vector for references to types that implement the concept ?

Directly writing the type as `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Hittable>>` gives error: an incomplete type. I tried a marker class that all Hittable will inherit from.

```cpp
class HitMarker {};

// Prevoiusly, no base class would be given
// and method hit is written directly.
class Sphere : HitMarker { ... };
...

class HittableList : HitMarker {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<HitMarker>> objects;
    ...
    bool hit(...) const {}
};
```

So, for a [function](https://raytracing.github.io/books/RayTracingInOneWeekend.html#surfacenormalsandmultipleobjects/commonconstantsandutilityfunctions) that expects Hittable, I could write

```cpp
// interface
Color ray_color(const Ray& ray, const IHittable& world) { ... }

// concept
template <Hittable H>
Color ray_color(const Ray& ray, const H& world)
```

However, the code will not compile. No method `hit` is found, inside the `HittableList`'s hit method.

I am trying to minimize runtime overhead. Is this not possible ?

Comment: You can use `std::variant` or `std::any`, but you will just end up reimplementing virtual calls, just more awkward.

Comment: Concepts can match entirely unrelated classes preventing you from storing them in a collection. the use of `std::variant` would require you to specify a list of possibilities which may not be well maintainable. An alternative to storing a collection would be to make `HittableList` a template class containing a tuple of shared pointers allowing you to make use of fold expressions, but this would prevent you from modifying the size of the "list": `template<Hittable ...Ts> class HittableList { std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<Ts>...> m_objects; };`

Comment: Sean parent's pattern might help.

Comment: "*How can I create a vector for references to types that implement the concept ?*" Why do you want to? Concepts aren't a replacement for base classes.

Comment: Concepts can't do that. They *only* restrict what template arguments you can pass to your templates. In exchange they give you better error messages when you get it wrong.

Comment: @NicolBolas To minimize runtime overhead, obviously. Not that it will work, but people do *want* it.

Answer (score 0):

Op here. Thank you everyone for responding. I have decided to use `std::variant`. However, some issues still prevail.

```cpp
template <typename Obj>
concept Hittable = requires(const Obj& obj) {
    { obj.hit() } -> std::same_as<bool>;
};

// All of them have the hit method
struct Sphere {};
struct Cube {};
struct Cone {};

// A match function to visit the variant

// https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit
template <class... Ts>
struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };

// explicit deduction guide (not needed as of C++20)
template <class... Ts>
overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

template <typename Val, typename... Ts>
auto match(Val& val, Ts... ts) {
    return std::visit(overloaded{ts...}, val);
}

// The aggregrate class
template <class T>
struct HittableList;

// A template template, basically tells the compiler
// that Geomtery is like T<Args...> where all Args impl Hittable
template <template <class...> class T, Hittable... Args1>
struct HittableList<T<Args1...>> {

    using Geometry = T<Args1...>;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Geometry>> objects;

    HittableList& add(std::shared_ptr<Geometry> obj);

    bool hit() const {
        for (const auto& obj : objects) {}
            match(*obj, [&]<Hittable H>(H& h) { ... });
        }
        return ret;
    }
};

int main() {
    using Geom = std::variant<Sphere, Cube, Cone>;

    HittableList<Geom> world;
    {
        Sphere s;
        Cube c;
        Cone k;

        world.add(std::make_shared<Geom>(s))
             .add(std::make_shared<Geom>(c))
             .add(std::make_shared<Geom>(k));
    }
    auto h = world.hit();
}
```

Is there a better way to efficiently move the geometry (s, c, k) into the `HittableList`. I am concerned about the times they are copied and also the lifetime of the geometry.

Also, for `HittableList`, I could not find a way to constraint the variant args without a template template.

I wonder if the code is any more efficient. I have enclosed both [concept-based](https://godbolt.org/z/hd86E68cx) and [inheritence-based](https://godbolt.org/z/Wd8oEc7zv) working example.

Additionally, I have included a way from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76255307/16182577) to combine variant types into a single variant type. So, that geometry defined in different headers can be combined before instantiating `HittableList`.

```cpp
template <class... Args>
struct coalesce;

// Fold first 2 and coalesce with remaining
template <template <class...> class T, class... Args1, class... Args2, typename... Remaining>
struct coalesce<T<Args1...>, T<Args2...>, Remaining...> {
    using type = typename coalesce<T<Args1..., Args2...>, Remaining...>::type;
};

// When type is not wrapped in some T<type>
// Note raw types can only be at the end
template <template <class...> class T, class... Args1, class... Args2>
struct coalesce<T<Args1...>, Args2...> {
    using type = coalesce<T<Args1..., Args2...>>::type;
};

// Base Case
template <template <class...> class T, class... Args1>
struct coalesce<T<Args1...>> {
    using type = T<Args1...>;
};

// Easier usecase
template <class... Args>
using coalesce_t = typename coalesce<Args...>::type;

static_assert(
    std::is_same_v<
        std::variant<int, long, short, char, double, float>,
        coalesce_t<
            std::variant<int, long, short>,
            std::variant<char>,
            double, float
        >
    >
);
```

But, I could not create the template for case where `coalesce_t<C, D, variant<A, B>>`. Unwrapped types have to be at the end.

Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: If you have another question, please [ask another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Anyway, I told you that you would end up reimplementing more awkward virtual calls.

Comment: "I have decided to use std::variant" It is unlikely to be any faster than your original version.